# Polymer: Where exactly do I put my Javascript for an Element?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have trouble loading Javascript in normal Polymer Elements:

Here is the test code that works perfectly fine, when executed without polymer:

```
 <body>
    <style>
    #content {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
    #button {padding: 10px 20px;}
    </style>

    <div id="content">
        <h1 id="title">Title</h1>

        <p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to the document.</p>


        <button id="button">Testbutton</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function popup2() {
            alert("What's up brow?");
            console.log("deine mudda");
        };

        var button = document.getElementById("button");
        button.addEventListener("click", popup2, false);
    </script>
</script>

</body>
```

But I want to use Javascript inside Polymer Elements and have tried the following insertions:

Nr. 1: Javascript inside the script tag, after the template tag:

```
 <polymer-element name="my-element">

    <template>
        <style>
        #content {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
        #button {padding: 10px 20px;}
        </style>

        <div id="content">
            <h1 id="title">Title</h1>

            <p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to the document.</p>


            <button id="button">Testbutton</button>
        </div>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('my-element', {
            popup: function() {
                alert('What the... dude?');
            },

            var button = document.getElementById("button");
            button.addEventListener("click", popup, false);

        });
    </script>

</polymer-element>
```

And this doesn't work. I get the error message in firefox: "SyntaxError: missing : after property id.
Chrome instead says: "SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier".

Both poin to the line "var button = document.getelementById("button");

According to the Polymer Documentation, javascript should just be placed at the end of the file:
https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-1.html

So in a second attempt, I place my Javascript directly inside the template tags like this:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">

    <template>
        <style>
        #content {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
        #button {padding: 10px 20px;}
        </style>

        <div id="content">
            <h1 id="title">Title</h1>

            <p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to the document.</p>


            <button id="button">Testbutton</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            function popup() {
                alert("jajaja");
            };

            var button = document.getElementById("button");
            button.addEventListener("click", popup, false);
        </script>

    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer('my-element', {


        });
    </script>

</polymer-element>
```

But this time I get: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null", which points agian to the line where I write: "button.addEventListener("click", popup, false);".

I guess this means, that the compiler can't see  the button id, because it is in the Shadow-Dom?

Please instruct me.

Comment: I don't know how to use polymer, but that's clearly invalid JS syntax. it starts as an object, and then in the middle switches to code...

Comment: Hey Karoly, how would you suggest writing it? Maybe it is really just my limitation with javascript, that is blocking me. I wrote the code three times. At which point are you referring, is the syntax invalid and how would you write it?

Comment: you get errors telling you that you use invalid syntax... ffs, read the error message.

Comment: I only get errors, when I implement the code into polymer. In raw html documents I get no errors. The syntax errors which I get I wrote above, and even after googling it, I couldn't find the error, which is the reason I am here to ask for assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">

  <template>
    <style>
    #content {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
    #button {padding: 10px 20px;}
    </style>

    <div id="content">
        <h1 id="title">Title</h1>

        <p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to the document.</p>


        <button on-tap="{{popup}}">Testbutton</button>
    </div>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer('my-element', {
        popup: function() {
            alert('alert');
        }
    });
  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

inside a polymer element you can bind directly to a function by using on-tap="{{function}}" attribute.

edited: all code didn't get into block

keeping eventlisteners in the js method

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">

  <template>
    <style>
    #content {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
    #button {padding: 10px 20px;}
    </style>

    <div id="content">
        <h1 id="title">Title</h1>

        <p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to the document.</p>


        <button id="button">Testbutton</button>
    </div>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer('my-element', {
        ready: function () {
            var button = this.$.button;
            button.addEventListener("click", function () {
                alert('alert');
            });
        }
    });
  </script>

</polymer-element>
```

edited again: OP wanted to keep html separate from JS

edited 1 more time: i think using a anonymous function is the easiest way to go here if not using the declarative method. code edited

Comment: I was hoping to completely separate my html from my javascript attirubtes like on-tap. I'll test this solution out, research a little bit and come back in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Thanks jimi. Don't want to be a dick, but I get: "Uncaught ReferenceError: popup is not defined".

Comment: maybe change the order of the functions. so it defines popup before ready. ill edit agian. if that doesn't work you can do anonymous function  button.addEventListener('click', function () { alert('alert'); });

Comment: Thanks Jimi, sorry for bothering you. Can you please explain one last time, where I can read about the "this.$.button"?. I would like to use something like this: "var button = document.querySelector("#button");"

Comment: this.$.button is the auto selector for inside polymer custom elements. allowing the element to easily find id's in the shadowdom. document.querySelector('#button') is a window level selector and it is my understanding that it can not be used inside a custom element. (i might be wrong on that haven't tried. much easier IMO to type less code) it is no bother. it is hard to learn without asking questions.

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll probably open a new question about this "document.querySelector()" in custom elements.

Answer (score 1):

script tag goes between closing template tag and closing polymer element tag or before the element definition but in this case when you call Polymer('my-element') you need to include tag name

Here is the example above with external js file, you can do the same with css

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">

  <template>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-element.css">

    <div id="content">
        <h1 id="title">Title</h1>

        <p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to the document.</p>


        <button id="button">Testbutton</button>
    </div>

  </template>
  <script src="my-element/my-element.js"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The folder name and js file name can be whatever you want but I think good practices you would structure like this

File Folder Structure

```
-myelements -folder 
--my-first-element -folder
  --my-first-element.html
  --my-first-element.css
  --my-first-element.js
--my-second-element -folder
  --my-second-element.html
  --my-second-element.css
  --my-second-element.js

<polymer-element name="ouch-button">
  <template>
    <button on-click="{{onClick}}">Send hurt</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      onClick: function() {
        alert('ouch', {msg: 'That hurt!'}); // fire(type, detail, targetNode, bubbles?, cancelable?)
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<ouch-button></ouch-button>
```

Comment: I have removed the links since they are outdated as of Polymer 1.0 although I believe the above method to include your external scripts still works.